# Dirac delta function of three variables with sum of vectors as an argument

Tags: integration, vectors, dirac-delta

I want to integrate the dirac delta function in the following expression:
$$f(\vec{k}_L) = N(k_L)\frac{K*}{X*^2} \int d^3\vec{k}_s \int d^2\vec{l} \frac{P1(k_s)}{P2(k_s)*C} g(\vec{k}_s) T(\vec{l}) \delta^3(\vec{k}_L + \vec{k}_s + \frac{\vec{l}}{X*}) $$

I was wondering how to do this with some of the functions depending on $\vec{k}_s$ and some just on $k_s$ and not a standard form of the dirac delta function (like $\delta^3(\vec{x}-\vec{a})$). An other thing I know is that $k_L << k_s$. How can I integrate this delta function?

Comment: Should it be $d^3 l$ (for $k_s + l$ to be defined)?

Comment: In the integral it really said $d^2l$, L is a 2D vector. But I just assumed the third component to be zero for the sum inside the dirac delta

Comment: Then the integral is
$$\int f(x, y) \,
 \delta(x_1 + a_1 y_1 + b_1) \,
 \delta(x_2 + a_2 y_2 + b_2) \,
 \delta(x_3 + b_3) \, dx dy,$$
which can be evaluated as an iterated integral (in any order). If we choose to eliminate $x$, we obtain
$$\int f((-a_1 y_1 - b_1, -a_2 y_2 - b_2, -b_3), y) \, dy.$$

Comment: I think I understand, now i did the following: $$f(\vec{k}_L) = N(k_L)\frac{K*}{X*^2} \int d^3\vec{k}_s \int d^2\vec{l} \frac{P1(k_s)}{P2(k_s)*C} g(\vec{k}_s) T(\vec{l}) \delta^2(\vec{k}_{L_{1,2}} + \vec{k}_{s_{1,2}} + \frac{\vec{l}}{X*}) \delta(k_{L_{3}} + k_{s_{3}}) $$ And when evaluating the integral over vector l,  it becomes:  $$f(\vec{k}_L) = N(k_L)K* \int d^3\vec{k}_s \frac{P1(k_s)}{P2(k_s)*C} g(\vec{k}_s) T(-X*\vec{k}_{L_{1,2}}-X*\vec{k}_{s_{1,2}}) \delta(k_{L_{3}} + k_{s_{3}}) $$

Comment: Then for the remaining delta:  $$f(\vec{k}_L) = N(k_L)\frac{K*}{X*^2} \int d^2\vec{k}_{s_{1,2}} \frac{P1(k_s)}{P2(k_s)*C} g(k_{s,{1}}, k_{s,{2}}, -k_{L,{3}}) T(-X*\vec{k}_{L_{1,2}}-X*\vec{k}_{s_{1,2}})$$ is this correct?

Comment: Essentially correct, but there shouldn't be an $(X^*)^2$ in the denominator in the last formula and $P_i(k_s)$ should be $P_i(k_{s, 1}, k_{s, 2}, -k_{L, 3})$.

Comment: Yes, the $X*^{-2}$ was a mistake, but the $P_{i}(k_{s})$ only depend on the length of $k_s$, should it be $P_{i}((k_{s,1}^2+k_{s,2}^2+(-k_{L,3})^2)^{1/2})$ then?

Comment: Right, I should have said that $P_i(\vec k_s)$ should become $P_i((k_{s, 1}, k_{s, 2}, -k_{L, 3}))$.